# unknown mutation type: isOpen/toggleSideBar [vuex]

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

i'm trying to toggle a sidebar in my nuxt project

I have this in my store;

```
export const state = () => ({
    isOpen: false
})

export const mutations = {
    toggleSideBar (state) {
        state.isOpen = !state.isOpen
    }
}

export const getters = {
    getDrawerState(state) {
        return state.isOpen
    }
}
```

in my navbar that contains the button, I have this:

```
import{mapMutations, mapGetters} from 'vuex'

...mapMutations({
            toggleSideBar: "isOpen/toggleSideBar"
        })
```

I have this is my default that where my class will be toggled:

```
import {mapGetters, mapMutations} from 'vuex'
computed:{
    ...mapGetters({
      isOpen:'isOpen/getDrawerState'
      })
  }
```

Comment: @DawoduFumbi It might be that you're not defining your module correctly. The modules are automatically declared based on filenames. Make sure your Nuxt project has `store/isOpen.js` for the `isOpen` module to be declared.

Comment: @tony19   So this one worked thank you, and I figured I was importing mapgetters and mapmutations in some components I didn't use them